# Notepad++ Delete Multiple Lines with Find in Files

Tags: notepad++, regex, find, find-and-replace

I  want to delete the whole line that contains certain words such as: build, name, disk.

I know that there is a search string `^.*?build.*$(\R|\Z)` which will find lines containing "build"

How do I change this to find "build" or "name" or "disk"?

Comment: What should be the result for `builder`, `rename` or `harddisk`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I change this to find "build" or "name" or "disk"?

Use the following search string:

```
^.*?(build|name|disk).*$(\R|\Z)
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)